# Outputting form data via classes

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how to output data from a form using classes. I've validated my form data in a validation PHP file and i'm using another file called database to output the text from my form to a file. I've tried using the function 'init' with multiple arguments: resulted in a blank file. Tried to hardcode the data: also blank.

```
class Database implements JsonSerializable
{
    public $name;
    public $age;
    public $email;
    public $phone;
    public $file = "database.txt";
    private $filehandler;
    public function __construct($name, $age, $email, $phone)
    {
        $this -> name = $name;
        $this -> age = $age;
        $this -> email = $email;
        $this -> phone = $phone;
    }
    public function init(){
        $this -> filehandler = fopen($this -> file, "w");
        fwrite($this -> file -> $this->filehandler, "Help");
        fclose($this -> filehandler);
    }
    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
       return ['name' => $this -> name,
                'age' => $this -> age,
                'email' => $this -> email,
                'phone' => $this -> phone
       ];
    }
}
```

Object creation:

```
$database = new Database($_POST['name'], $_POST['age'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['phone']);

$database->jsonSerialize();
$database->init();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
        fwrite($this -> file -> $this->filehandler, "Help");
```

to

```
        fwrite($this -> filehandler, "Help");
```

Full code

```
<?php

class Database implements JsonSerializable
{
    public $name;
    public $age;
    public $email;
    public $phone;
    public $file = "database.txt";
    private $filehandler;

    public function __construct($name, $age, $email, $phone)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->age = $age;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->phone = $phone;
    }

    public function init()
    {
        $this->filehandler = fopen($this->file, "w");
        fwrite($this->filehandler, $this->jsonSerialize());
        fclose($this->filehandler);
    }

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return json_encode(
            [
                'name'      => $this->name,
                'age'       => $this->age,
                'email'     => $this->email,
                'phone'     => $this->phone
            ]
        );
    }
}

// $database = new Database($_POST['name'], $_POST['age'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['phone']);
$database = new Database('test', 100, 'test@email.com', 999);
$database->init();
```

Comment: Oh, well that solved the issue of outputing, how would i go about getting the data from the form tho?

Comment: Replace "Help" with `$this->jsonSerialize()` and `return json_encode([]);` in `jsonSerialize()`

Comment: The ouput is right but its returning {"name":null... etc